# Node.js request body has some extra padding

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am making a `POST` request in `nodejs` which returns `protobuf` that I need to pass to another function that will use it as the body of another request.

The problem is, when I log the returned `body` from the request, it seems to have some extra bytes at the front like these (Base64 encoded) `H4sIAAAAAAAAAAFxPY7C`

I've tried getting the body as a raw buffer and also as `base64` but these extra bytes are always there, yet they are not there when I proxy the initial `POST` request.

I am making the request like this:

```
var requestParams = 
{
  uri: 'https://www.myurl',
  method: 'POST',
  encoding: 'base64',
  timeout: 4000,
  headers: 
  {
    'User-Agent': 'My Request',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
  },
  body: myBody,
  tunnel: false // Used for proxy
};

var requestCompletion = function(error, response, body)
{
    console.log(error);
    response ? console.log(response.statusCode) : null
    console.log('RESULT: ' + body + '\n\n\n');

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    {
        // Success
        nextFunction(body);
    }
    else
    {
        errorFunction(error + ' : ' + response.statusCode);
    }
}

request(requestParams, requestCompletion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with making gzip parameter true:

```
var requestParams = 
{
   uri: 'https://www.myurl',
   method: 'POST',
   encoding: 'base64',
   timeout: 4000,
   gzip: true,
   headers: 
          {
          'User-Agent': 'My Request',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
          },
    body: myBody,
   tunnel: false // Used for proxy
   };
```

Comment: That worked :) I didn't know it had that parameter. Thanks